# Reformatting row contents for an emailed Google Forms response

Tags: email, google-apps-script, formatting, google-forms

I have a private Google Form that I use to quote clients.
The form data is emailed after clicking on the submit button; the trigger is set up and the email successfully sends, but the rows and columns are not separate as it is in the form.

Data is sent like this (just a snap):

> ,Once signed, please Fax, mail or e-mail it to the provided address.,,,,,,,,,,Above information is not an invoice and only an estimate of services/goods described above.,,P

The form values should be separated row by row, is that possible?

This is my Google Apps Script:

```
function mail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;
  var numRows = 56;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var row = data;
  var emailAddress = '******@gmail.com';
  var subject = "Subject...";
  var message = row;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message)    
}
```

//1(R1),1(C1),55(R1),11(C1

Comment: Your data is 2 dimensional object. The first row is data[0]. It has 56 rows so the last row is data[55]. Each row has 2 elements. The first element of the first row is data[0][0] and the second element is data[0][1]. Generally users put information for different email recipients on different row and using a for loop they iterate through the row and assemble each message from different columns.

Comment: There a lot of email examples on this site. Search for them.

Comment: Look into javascript array